# How to use wso2cep in my case?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am working with wso2cep3.0. I went through the docs of wso2cep but there is no exaplanation about wso2cep how  would i use it
1.what is the use of `Input Event Adapter`:-in my concern for getting the data from client.
2.`Event Builder` means incoming data format specifier.
3.`Event Formatter` means Outgoing data format specifier.
4`.Output Event Adapter` out put handler.
but how can i use this thing means any program or any event writer most important how would i publish this to external world example as http endpoint or https or jms.
I am unable to understand how would i start and where can i start.
Please suggest me i know the ESB,DSS,IS,BPS

Comment: it means how we can start process first what we need to implement input event or formater..

Answer (score 1):

For a typical CEP usecase, you configure the input event adaptor to connect to an event source, such as a JMS endpoint, Thrift endpoint(WSO2Event adaptor in CEP 3.0.0) etc. Event builder specifies how the incoming message will be mapped.

Next the execution plans will have the actual query (the processing part) of the execution flow. This is where the CEP engine actually processes the events.

Event formatter formats it to an output format as needed. The output event adaptor connects to the actual endpoint to which the processed result would be published. It would go and publish to a JMS endpoint, email, database etc.

To get started, you need to create an input event adaptor, then an event builder that uses the input event adaptor, then the execution plan, then the output event adaptor, and an event formatter that would format the result from the execution plan and send to the relevant output adaptor. You can find the flow in [1].

You can find example configurations in /samples/artifacts directory. You can find an overview of samples in [2] and can find how to run them [3]. Each sample has an associated producer and a consumer that simulates real world event producers/consumers. Samples would be the best place to learn more about CEP configurations.

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/display/CEP300/CEP+Configuration+Overview
[2] http://docs.wso2.org/display/CEP300/Overview+of+Samples
[3] http://docs.wso2.org/display/CEP300/Setting+up+CEP+Samples

Comment: Thanx for reply i got u clearly my source is jms so how would i write the qurey for process my data

Comment: To use JMS, you need to create a JMS input event adaptor, configure it accordingly and map with an appropriate event builder. The event builder will transform your event to a stream compatible for the WSO2 CEP(Siddhi) engine. You can refer to [WSO2 Siddhi language docs](http://docs.wso2.org/display/CEP300/Siddhi+Language+Specification) . Sample 0103 for CEP uses JMS and might help you further in your configuration.

Comment: i find this query in excutionplan configuration but they are not explain about input jms message and output jms messge how its look like my query is                 from flightStatsStream[status != 'On-Time']
select flightName, flightId, flightType, arrivalTime, trackNo
insert into delayedFlightStream

Comment: Hi, you can use [CEP Event Tracer](http://docs.wso2.org/display/CEP300/CEP+Event+Tracer) to find out more about how the event comes and goes out of CEP. You can enable tracing to each separate artifact related to event flow (e.g. for Input Event Adaptor, Event Builder, Execution Plan and so on)

Comment: i have done this but my inputeventadaptor is not working as per desire way